# MaxMSP: Carry count on counter object

Tags: max-msp-jitter

I am using the counter object in MaxMSP, and I have the carry count number (right outlet) increasing every time a counter cycle is completed.
However, every time I reset the counter (by sending a 0 to its forth inlet) and send also a 0 to the carry count, the carry count will still continue from where it stopped last time (I guess, it is supposed to be like this).

How can I make it so, that when I reset the counter, I can get my carry count also starting from 0?
I can’t get this to work.

thanks in advance for any help! Ilias

Comment: It would be good if you could add your test patch (select max objects, choose Edit -> Copy Compressed), paste here.

Answer (score 1):

To fully reset the counter you have to send a list of 3 times 0 - "0 0 0" to the counter object. Here is a simple example:

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
728.3oc0WssbaBCD8Y7WACO65AIg4ReqeGc53Q.arUFPvHDoNMS92qtXrcSB
WriCi6KvnkEw4bVsW3kENdoU6gFO2u69SWGmWV33XLoM3bXsiWIceVAsw3lG
G9cU5idKsORB6kFyR2BW+NqMxmK.i4NK71RFu.jl8.cxXUqryJ9fUqI4y0fE
Vp8v0iwUelecviZpLaGiuci.xjVmPIwq7W5FhzWQA95aX7J+iuCK2fGEz+FJ
wSa60EKzWVNQdWBMMzsv6Htuq+jIN9CINpWhOAFiMTkDMHgiuFBm1JkU7OUH
syZs.Z.tjJYU7ynPPThMbQVsVg9.CGBNiCuSQRo7sCpJ3.iRfPI8rkmIKDx0
HKYUkkJt7tyAYTg3Y2rp1SO6jlsCJpefU.aJnoPwEnf98SURXhMnaHYTT2og
Ojp3aIUUN4J.Z1NHelnJxR0Ph9Vb7fTEcSoJiOuTEmr1vtDS7LNXHphupBYJ
njBhKLu9gJtrg8GimHcT3hqfOZpaWP1dddssDNoGlerhqFXbZokB+PvnGiC0
TgxtDDa.NM0RR+qPujUa2V.ek0AWisIuwQckqFqN3XsC6NEYSXFtLHJ7+PEy
2PLBFcyTrHzY4cinXnashculSdncJgfFOmLY9RI6aVrbH6BmDaRZ30MfFwdF
EYUMx5gztvAztan9v32Q5CN1HIHr4FIbH8I91pO87OLlg2.gZfdjavDEp0Wh
PELT0ok1bxo72NcS4lXDsDzPRGYZRm4U8JX7292flOu19+pmMUshrN3e3upT
H5HBxgFIiapaelS591tmf4NVdNvOehnbVitvPd+UFtH73OBdHyGbhm.bdCl+
JwCYBQKcetYDN3wfS3rBGx8yYYxDN6LiGcH2UYVg2UnI9KDM1Zzz55m.Qygs
z.DU2sGqD5kQKMKYb6RhYo.dh04uoWsGUnZoHU8SZE19A6isif3UVkCBdKy3
6B8W90E+EnWpaFJ
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Comment: the three values are "carryCount up/down/updown currentcount"